# Datasource XX.XX.X.XX could not be found

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

When I am running the same piece of code(cfquery) from another server it runs fine however, when I tried to access it from another server, I am getting the following error:

Datasource XX.XX.X.XX could not be found

Both has Coldfusion 8 installed.

any idea?

Comment: Server #2 doesn't have Datasource XX.XX.X.XX configured as a datasource in the CF Administrator?

Comment: Yeah, that could be the reason. How to check that? And is it possible to configure two datasource in a CF administrator?

Comment: Yes, you can configure as many as you want. It's in the /CFIDE/Administrator section under Datasources.

Comment: How to know what link I should type in my Web Browser to get access to administrator?

Comment: Log onto the server and try `http://localhost:8500/cfide/administrator` - if that doesn't work ask the server admin what it is.

Comment: Assuming you have access to it, its usually located at http://www.yourwebsitehere.com/CFIDE/Administrator or http://127.0.0.1/CFIDE/Administrator or http://localhost/CFIDE/Administrator... if you're on a shared host, you're probably out of luck.... you'll have to either use a control panel or ask their administrators to add a datasource for you.